# tronweb - Require authorization for transaction in Tron DApp

Tags: transactions, authorization, tron, tronweb

I'm working on realize a new Tron DApp, very simple. But I'm newbie so I'm working starting from this tutorial:
https://blog.yudiz.com/build-your-first-dapp-on-tron-blockchain/

It helps me a lot.
So, here what I've made:

1. I've installed TronLink on my Chrome browser and I've selected the Shasta Network;
2. I've create a new Account (for easy, I named it "A");
3. I've got the Private Key and the wallet address from TronLink (I'll use it later);
4. I've cloned and installed the Tron-DAPP.git repository with the command:

   ```
   npm install
   ```
5. Then, I've configured the index.js within private key and the Address "A";
6. Then, on https://tronide.io I've loaded the HelloWorld.sol contract, and thanks to Plugins **Solidity Compiler** and **DEPLOYMENT** I've compiled and deployed my contract; this generates a popup with the unique hash of my contract; it has got the TronLink account to require authorization to public this contract on Shasta Network;
7. Using this hash, I've searched it on https://shasta.tronscan.org/ to get the Contract Address;
8. I've copied this one on the file index.js;
9. Starting the DApp with:

   ```
   node index
   ```

I've reached my app using 127.0.0.1:8001; **Great! It works!**

Now, my question: If I use my Address "A" in order to use the Contract action "postMessage()", it consumes TRX for transaction, and all things is done successfully. But if I use another Tron Wallet Address, like "B", I don't get any consume of TRX, but more important it don't require me authorization to proceed.

Instead, if I proceed on https://shasta.tronscan.org, and I make access on my Contract, within TronLink on Address "B", when I make "postMessage()" in order to write on my Contract, it requires me the authorization, and after that I consume TRX for the transaction.

What's wrong in this DApp? Why it doesn't require authorization when I make "postMessage()"?

thanks for your precious help.

Answer (score 1):

It does not require authorization because your dApp has your private key. If an dApp has your private key has total control over your wallet.